# Perform Action on Navigation Header - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am performing an action on the Navigation header where i have a text called "log in user". The "log in user" text is in a layout file called navheader.

On my home page(main activty), is where i want to perform the activity. When i draw out the navigation drawer and click on the "log in user", i get an exception thrown `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**nav_header.axml**

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOG IN"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/login"/>
```

**Main Activity.cs**

```
loginUser = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.login);

loginUser.Click += login_User;

 private void login_User(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(loginPage));
        this.StartActivity(intent);


    }
```

Comment: How does your `OnCreate` method of your MainActivity.cs file looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` you can't directly access to the views inside your header view from `MainActivity` because your header view is not direct part of your xml code for `MainActivity`. You will have to do something like this:

```
var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view); //whatever your Id for navigationview is
var headerView = navigationView.GetHeaderView(0);
var loginUser = headerView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.login);

loginUser.Click += login_User;

private void login_User(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(loginPage));
    this.StartActivity(intent);
}
```